# Python Eel does not return correct value

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I'm making a desktop program with Python Eel. I'm having a trouble. My code is very simple.

main.py:

```py
import sqlite3, eel

eel.init('UI')

@eel.expose
def get_data():
    return "I got it"

eel.start('index.html')
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendor/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Müşteri Takip</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h2 id="hh2">degiscen mi!</h2>
                <input id="buton" type="button" value="Button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

index.js:

```js
async function yo() {
    document.getElementById('hh2').innerHTML = eel.get_data()();
}
$('#buton').click(function() {
    yo();
})
```

But when I click button, this is what it changes to: [image]

Why is this happening? It is super simple code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that "eel.get_data()" returns a promise and not the desired value. To fix this, you must use the ".then()" method to wait for the promise to resolve and then assign its value to "hh2". Here's the corrected code:
index.js:

```
async function yo() {
  eel.get_data().then(function(data) {
  document.getElementById('hh2').innerHTML = data;
 });
}
 $('#buton').click(function() {
  yo();
})
```

Best!